How to inject text to microsoft bot framework webchat. I am using Webchat javascript
I want to add and send a message in Microsoft chatbot without typing that message on textArea which is at the bottom of the Bot window. I need to give the message as an activity from user side.
We have tried to set the text value using the below code but it just show message in the textarea but when we click the button message did not reach to the chatbot backend code.
$('.webchat__send-box-text-box__input').val("test hi this ")
$('.webchat__send-box-text-box__input').attr("value","test hi this ")
I found this approach that works for ReactJS.
componentDidMount(){
document.getElementsByClassName('wc-shellinput')[0].value = "testMsg"
    console.log(this.chat);
    this.chat.shellRef.props.onChangeText('testMsg');      
  }


Does this answer your question? React Modifying Textarea Values

I usually rely on the hooks provided by webchat
Thy are documented in [the webchat documentation on github][1]
In you case this should be sufficient:
const [sendBoxValue, setSendBoxValue] = useSendBoxValue();

setSendBoxValue('testMsg');

  [1]: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/main/docs/HOOKS.md

